# Unable to get response from GlideRecord servicenow-rest for ticket update

Tags: node.js, servicenow, servicenow-rest-api

I am using Node.js and `var GlideRecord = require('servicenow-rest').gliderecord;` for creating and updating a ticket in ServiceNow.

I am able to create a ticket through node code and getting the sys_id but I am not able to close the ticket. I am not getting any response or errors either.

Here is the code snippet:

```
gr = new GlideRecord("xxx", "yyy", "zzz", "aaa");
var obj2 = {
    comments: "Ticket closed",
    state: "7",

}
gr.update(sys_id, obj2).then(function (error, response) {
    console.log(response);
    console.log(error);
});
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the same update in the client or via a rest call without this library as I don’t see how to log the error. It’s likely there’s a abort business rule disallowing the update, however that doesn’t generally show up in the rest response.

Try setting state to 6 aka resolved. If that works look at the business rules and considering suggesting changing the logic on aborting the update to meet your need.